# Change the page layout for the Product Home Page

Tags: page-layout, tab, product, view

I've been searching for how to do this for a couple of hours; and getting quietly frustrated.

I have created a simple app which lists products. I don't need to use price books, opportunities or anything else. I have set a tab for my app for the Product standard object, and it takes me to a page layout which includes views in sections for Price books, Product Views and Asset views, underneath these is the list of recent products.

The only bit I need is the "recent products" list, but I can't find anyway of removing the 3 views above it.

If it helps, the tab link goes to xxx.salesforce.com/01t/o 
if I remove the /o from the end of this I get what I need!

Any suggestions? I'm sure this is pretty simple, but I just can't find the page layout related to it. I have changed the product detail page, and the product list contents, but can't get this to do as I please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit Update**: Updated the answer as per Vamsi's suggestion in the comments i.e. no need of a controller and can be achieved via VF page.

**Create a new VF Page:**

```
<apex:page action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product2.List, $ObjectType.Product2)}"/>
```

Go to **Customize->Products->Buttons and Links**

Edit the **"Products Tab"**

Under the Override Properties section, for "Override With" property , select the visualforce page name which we have created above.

We have now successfully overriden the Products tab. Whenever you click on the products tab the user would be redirected to the URL which ends with '/01t'.

Comment: we can do the redirect with just vf page action attribute. no need of a controller. <apex:page action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product2.List, $ObjectType.Product2)}"/>

Comment: Interesting! Didnt know about this. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thanks everyone: I used Rajiv Bhatt's solution in combination with Vamsi Krishna's comment. 2 minutes later - all done. Look great - just what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler solution would be to create a custom link.
Customize > Home > Custom Links
your Content Source should be URL > in your case > /01t

Then create a new Tab for your object or just a new visualforce Tab and select your new custom link as Splash Page Custom Link.

This will do the work and redirect you when pressing the tab to your desired URL.